# How to properly make path handling robust in a bash program?

Tags: bash, path, relative-path

- The script have some hard-coded relative paths. I would like them to be relative to script position.
- The script needs to change current directory as some other program (cmake) needs it.
- The script takes some (possibly relative to caller) paths as an argument and it passes them to that program, they should be derelativized.

Questions are inline:

```
#!/bin/sh

# First arg should be Release or Debug    
# TODO test for that.

if test -n "$1"; then          # BTW how to test whether $1 is Debug or Release?
  BUILD_TYPE="$1"
else
  BUILD_TYPE="Release"
fi

# Set install prefix to current directory, unless second argument is given. 

if test -n "$2"; then
  INSTALL_PREFIX="$2"    # How to derelativize this path argument?
else
  INSTALL_PREFIX=bin     # How to make this path relative to script location?
fi

# Make build directory and do cmake, make, make install.

mkdir -p build/${BUILD_TYPE} && # How to make this path relative to script location?
cd build/${BUILD_TYPE} &&

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${BUILD_TYPE} \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${INSTALL_PREFIX} \ # Possible relative to caller current directory. 
      ../../ &&             # Relative to scrip position.
make -j4 &&
make install
```

Is it a common problem or am I doing something in a non-standard way?

Comment: I don't ask you to remake a script, I just need a guide how to do it in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
test $1 == "Debug"
```

2) 
Put

```
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname $0)"
ORIGINAL_DIR="$(pwd)"
```

at the top of the script (first non-comment line after `#!` line)

To make a variable absolute relative to the script:

```
[ "${VAR/#\//}" != "$VAR" ] || VAR="$SCRIPT_DIR/$VAR"
```

To make it relative to the starting directory:

```
[ "${VAR/#\//}" != "$VAR" ] || VAR="$ORIGINAL_DIR/$VAR"
```

Basically we replace a leading slash with empty `"${VAR/#\//}"` and compare with `"$VAR"`, if they are different then `$VAR` is absolute. Otherwise we prepend a directory that we want to make it absolute.

Comment: I found readlink -f command, but I'm not sure whether it help. Can you comment?

Comment: readlink -f deals with symlinks, not with making paths absolute. You shouldn't need to canonicalise the paths you are given, as you can read via symlinks.

Comment: ./ is a relative path, and gets treated as such. It won't cause any problems for programs to read paths containing /./ although you might want to tidy up before displaying the path to the user.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what [Douglas Leeder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536772/how-to-properly-make-path-handling-robust-in-a-bash-program/1536840#1536840) said, I’d recommend to *always* surround your variables in double quotes to prevent paths with space characters messing up your script.